# Is there a way to split vectors in single character

Tags: r

Is there a way to split this vector into 2

```
> c("asd,df")
[1] "asd,df"
```

expected output

```
[1] "asd" "df"
```

Comment: Nope this returns as list ````strsplit(c("asd,df"),split=',', fixed=TRUE)````

Comment: So `unlist` them

Comment: `unlist(strsplit(c("asd,df"),split=',', fixed=TRUE))` in case it wasn't clear. Or take the first item of the list `strsplit(c("asd,df"),split=',', fixed=TRUE)[[1]]`.